# zap meta-tag "comparison"

Tags: discussion

The tag [comparison](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparison) is a "meta tag" of the type which serves no useful purpose. There's no situation where tying comparisons of various types into a group makes much sense — and on the other hand, almost *any* question has some aspect of comparison. Can we nuke this tag?

Comment: I agree, it serves no useful purpose. I think nuking tags is something only SEN admins can do, though.

Comment: I'm told that if the tag is removed from all questions, it will just go away.

Comment: I can't remove it from all questions, because I can't edit the merged question here: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9790/what-are-the-advantages-of-a-micro-4-3s-camera-compared-to-a-dslr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tag is no longer used, so it is effectively zapped now.